# How to set colours in biplot PCA analysis in R

Tags: r, colors, pca

Im very new to the R environment and started using it on a practice file.
i'v created a biplot (biplot is what im required to do) and mange to choose the PC's i wanted. Iv looked for an answer which might be there but i dont understand all the arguments meaning yet and so i might missed the answer.

```
mat=read.csv('data.txt',sep="\t",row.name=1,check.names=F,header=T)
mat_as_matrix<-as.matrix(mat)
tmat=t(mat_as_matrix)
pca_tmat=prcomp(tmat)
biplot(pca_tmat, choices=c(3,4), col=c("blue","green"))
```

My input data is like that:

```
Taxon   S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6  S7  S8  S9  S10 S11
OTU1    45  32  34  55  32  4   12  2   1   4   15
OTU2    1   2   3   2   1   23  32  21  26  34  23
OTU3    1   1   2   1   3   1   2   1   2   1   1
OTU4    12  21  23  45  31  342 342 345 333 322 150
```

I also made a few attemts like the following to remove the arrows. i'm trying to remove the OTU's lables and turn the 'Sn' labels to be points

```
biplot(pca_tmat$x,pca_tmat$y,type="p", var.axes = F, choices=c(3,4), col=c('blue','green')['S1','S3'])
```

but i get the following error without any changes:
Error in 1L:p : argument of length 0

What i need to do is to give each sample a different color: Sx, Sy,Sz 1st color Si, Sj 2nd color, Sa,Sb 3rd color, etc...

Comment: Sorry, colours of what exactly? The points, the line, the axes, the text, etc...

Comment: Could you post some example code and data?

Comment: @will.pearse Ive upded the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do that with `biplot`, but if you work with the raw PCA output you can do essentially anything you want. Maybe something like:

`data <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))
pca <- prcomp(data)
raw <- pca$x[,1:2]
plot(raw[,1], raw[,2], col=rainbow(nrow(raw)), pch=20)`

...will give you what you're looking for. Notice how I've extracted the raw PCA output, letting me make my own bi-plot.

It sounds a little like this is a homework question; if it is, then I promise you that working with the output of `prcomp` will give you a better understand of what's going on in a PCA. It'll be worth the effort :D

Comment: Thank you, and this is not a homework question its a practice before analysing my own data. i will give a try, thank you again